# verification of the existence of connected user

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

i have used custom **Membershipprovider** and **roleprovider** class in my asp.net mvc4 application.

this code works fine :

```
[OutputCache(Duration =0, NoStore= true)]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl)
         { 
            return View(new User());
                  }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(User u, string ReturnUrl) {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(u.login, u.password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.login, false);
               if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.login).Contains("user")) return RedirectToAction("Index");
                else return RedirectToAction("Common");
            }
            else {
                return View(u);
            }
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "user")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
         [Authorize(Roles="admin")]
        public ActionResult Common()
        {
            return View();
        }

         public ActionResult SignOut()
         {
             FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
              return RedirectToAction("Login");
         }
    }
```

But i need to verify if the existence of a connected user in the `Login` action

```
 public ActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl)
             { 
              //verification and redirection if connected
                return View(new User());
                      }
```

I need to know:

1. What are the different manners to do that?
2. What is the best one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "verify the existence of a connected user." Can you elaborate?

Comment: if i log in with an administrateur account, i get the welcome administration page if i go back without signout i wouldn't see the authentification page , i have to get the current page

Comment: Are you looking for `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check this way:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
// user logged in already
}
```